# is it a good idea to store a delegate in a session(user)? any risk of memory leak or other kind of issue?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if it's a good idea to store a delegate of a method sitting in a aspx page into the session

the project that I work on does it and I have a bad feeling about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be a bad idea if this were ever to scale to multi-server environment as I'm pretty sure your not going to be able to ensure that the pointer to the  memory location that contains the method will be the same on every server casuing some nasty errors.

Answer (score 0):

Umm, what are these methods needed for, and wouldn't use just create an instance of the delegate as needed. Or have some Static/Shared method somewhere...??